# Why doesn't this javascript command execute?

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin.forms, webview

```
webview.Eval("var list = document.getElementsByClassName('some button class')[0].click();");
        webview.Eval("document.getElementById('savebutton').click();");
```

From the first instruction, the program enters a page where there is a save button, then the second line would be to click the save button.

This whole code should run when I press a button but my problem is that when I press the button, only the first instruction is executed. If I press the button again, the second half will also be executed.

Does anyone have any idea what to do? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try putting the js code of the second line after the `;` of the first like so `webview.Eval("var list = document.getElementsByClassName('some button class')[0].click(); document.getElementById('savebutton').click();");
`

Comment: If that doesn't work  you probably have a typo in the Id or maybe it should have been a Class instead of an Id.

Comment: @ChristophEckinger Thanks for the quick response. I tried both of them but still not works.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you comment the link you want to access here. I'll go and take a look at it

Comment: And make sure you give me the actual names of the class (line 1) and Id (line 2) as well

Comment: @ChristophEckinger I would be very happy to share the link with you, but unfortunately I have to log in within the site and unfortunately I can't tell the password, plus the whole page is in Hungarian.

Comment: @ChristophEckinger Anyway, thank you for trying to help

Comment: Alright then you can do it too. Go to the Website in your browser, press Ctrl Shift I on Chrome or Ctrl Shift J on Firefox, go to the html viewer which is called Elements in Chrome click in there, press Ctrl F and !Copy! the id name you use into the search field. Check if the element you want to find is the first with that id on the website (GetElement will return the first element it finds), if it is actually an id (could be another attribute) and check if you find it all

Comment: @ChristophEckinger I found it, but there is only one piece of it.

Comment: Can you share more of the code?

Comment: @ChristophEckinger I think the problem is that the page has an autocomplete script and maybe its the reason why the save button not working suddenly, just when I click that one more time. I tried to set a time delay in js, or delay it with Thread.Sleep() but non of them work. Its like the two code runs at the same time, and the seccond line of code has no time to wait the first. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I can help you with the code but without access to the website it will be hard if not impossible for me to answer if there is a fix. It's just to many possible options for me.

Comment: @ChristophEckinger Finally, I solve the problem. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: @Bence, that is great that you solved your problem. Please add an "Answer" below, describing what worked. This will help others. (And also let those trying to help you know that there is an answer that works. Its hard to read all the comments to discover you solved it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I used `Device.StartTimer()` method to delay the execution of the second line.

```
TimeSpan delay = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
Device.StartTimer(delay, DelayHandler);
webview.Eval("var list = document.getElementsByClassName('some button class')[0].click();");


bool DelayHandler()
{
 webview.Eval("document.getElementById('savebutton').click();");
 return false;
}
```